# 2007 jeep liberty 3.7 only start I completely remove "any" sparkplug from cylinder then ground,

Tags: starting, ignition, sparkplugs, compression, ground

Only starts take out any one plug then ground to alternator starts right up, thought had to be bad ground so grounded from battery to engine block still won't start with all six plugs in Jeep Liberty take One plug out at a time ground plug to alternator Jeep starts right up was told could be blocked converter or muffler compression issue or bad ground

Comment: Can you add a photo of what you do to get it to start?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you explain better how it isn't starting? Does it not crank over at all (starter doesn't push engine around)? Does it crank over, but nothing fires (no spitting or kicking from the engine)? Does it start but immediately die? When you pull a plug and it "starts right up", how does it run and does it continue running? What's going on. What you've stated so far isn't a lot of information.